back to prev page product position in woocommerce infinit scroll
In woocommerce archive / category and taxonomy pages I create an infinit scroll for products. this is my code so far:
functions.php
add_filter('woocommerce_product_loop_start', 'add_data_page_to_products_list');
function add_data_page_to_products_list($output){
    // Use regex to match the opening <ul> tag and add the data-page="1" attribute
    $output = preg_replace('/<ul class="products([^"]*)">/', '<ul class="products$1" data-page="1">', $output);

    return $output;
}

/******************** Remove Pagination & add load more button insted of it ********************/
remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10);

// Add a Load More button after the product loop
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'custom_load_more_button', 15);
function custom_load_more_button(){
    global $wp_query;

    $total_products = $wp_query->found_posts; // Get the total number of products available

    echo '<div id="loader" class="loader-styles" data-page="1" data-total-product-number="' . $total_products . '" style="display: none; text-align: center;">';
    echo '<div class="loader-styles__a"></div>';
    echo '<div class="loader-styles__b"></div>';
    echo '<div class="loader-styles__c"></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}

// Pass posts_per_page and ajax URL to JavaScript
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_infinit_products_scripts');
function enqueue_infinit_products_scripts() {

    if (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('infinit-products', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/product-infinite-scroll.js', [], null, true);

        // Get the posts_per_page setting from WordPress

        // $posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');

        // Pass ajax URL and posts_per_page to JavaScript

        wp_localize_script('infinit-products', 'ajax_params', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),

            // 'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, // Passing the setting to JS
        ));
    }
}

js:

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    /******************* Ajax Infinite Scroll with Loader *******************/
    if (document.querySelector(".products")) {
        let canLoad = true;
        let page = 1;
        const productWrapper = document.querySelector(".products");
        const loader = document.getElementById("loader");
        const baseUrl = window.location.href.split("page/")[0];
        const totalProducts = parseInt(loader.getAttribute('data-total-product-number'), 10); // Get total number of products
        const initialPage = parseInt(window.location.href.split("page/")[1]) || 1; // Get the page number from URL, default to 1

        // Function to load products up to a specific page
        function loadProductsUpToPage(targetPage) {
            let loadCompleted = 0;

            function loadNextPage() {
                if (loadCompleted >= targetPage) return; // Stop if we've loaded up to the target page
                loadCompleted++; // Increment first to keep track of the correct page

                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.open("GET", `${baseUrl}page/${loadCompleted}/`, true);
                xhr.onload = function() {

                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        const parser = new DOMParser();
                        const doc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, "text/html");
                        const newProducts = doc.querySelectorAll(".products .product");

                        newProducts.forEach((product) => {
                            productWrapper.appendChild(product);
                        });

                        if (loadCompleted < targetPage) {
                            loadNextPage();
                        } else {
                            canLoad = true;
                            updateUrl(targetPage);

                            if (productWrapper.querySelectorAll(".product").length >= totalProducts) {
                                loader.style.display = "none"; // Hide loader if all products are loaded

                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                xhr.send();
            }
            loadNextPage();
        }

        // Initial load if coming directly to a specific page
        if (initialPage > 1) {
            canLoad = false;
            loadProductsUpToPage(initialPage);
        }

        function loadMoreProducts() {
            if (!canLoad) return;

            canLoad = false;
          
            loader.style.display = "flex"; // Show the loader

            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open("GET", `${baseUrl}page/${page + 1}/`, true);
            xhr.onload = function() {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    const parser = new DOMParser();
                    const doc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, "text/html");
                    const newProducts = doc.querySelectorAll(".products .product");

                    if (newProducts.length) {
                        newProducts.forEach((product) => {
                            productWrapper.appendChild(product);

                        });
                        page++;
                        canLoad = true;
                        loader.style.display = "none"; // Hide loader
                        updateUrl(page);

                        if (productWrapper.querySelectorAll(".product").length >= totalProducts) {
                            loader.style.display = "none"; // Hide loader if all products are loaded
                        }
                    } else {
                        loader.style.display = "none"; // Hide loader if no more products
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        }

        // Update the URL with the current page
        function updateUrl(pageNumber) {
            const newUrl = pageNumber > 1 ? `${baseUrl}page/${pageNumber}/` : baseUrl;

            window.history.replaceState({
                page: pageNumber
            }, "", newUrl);
        }

        // Function to check if the user has reached the bottom of the product list
        function checkScrollPosition() {
            const scrollPosition = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
            const productListBottom = productWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + window.scrollY;

            // Trigger loading when the user reaches the bottom of the products list
            if (scrollPosition >= productListBottom && canLoad) {
                loadMoreProducts();
            }
        }

        // Trigger product loading when the user scrolls
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
            checkScrollPosition();
        });

        // Update the current page in the URL based on scroll position
        function determineCurrentPage() {
            const products = document.querySelectorAll(".products .product");
            let visiblePage = page;

            products.forEach((product, index) => {
                const rect = product.getBoundingClientRect();
                if (rect.top < window.innerHeight && rect.bottom > 0) {
                    visiblePage = Math.ceil((index + 1) / 20); // Adjust this divisor according to how many products are on each page
                }
            });

            if (visiblePage !== page) {
                page = visiblePage;
                updateUrl(page);
            }
        }

        // Update page URL based on visible product list during scrolling
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
            determineCurrentPage();
        });
    }
});

css:
.loader-styles {
    width: 100%;
    height: 6em;
    margin: 1.5em;
    justify-content: center 
}
.loader-styles__a, .loader-styles__b, .loader-styles__c {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    animation: bounce1 1s linear infinite 
}
.loader-styles__a {
    background: var(--primary-color) 
}
.loader-styles__b {
    background: var(--secondary-color);
    animation-delay: .1s 
}
.loader-styles__c {
    background: #255ff4;
    animation-delay: .2s 
}

now a feature that I want to add is for example when scroll down to page 3 and click on a product and go to it's page then want to back and see prev page, it should load all products from page one to 3 and stand on the product that I clicked. now it just show page 3 products with url of page 3 and when I scroll down to the loader, it shows page 1 products and url changed to /page/2/ and so on. can anyone write a code for that part?
